# App.config connectionString change at startup

Tags: c#, .net, connection-string, app-config

I have a very short question that is partially answered but doesn't seem to work.

I have my SQL Server with its database.

I want to change the app.config's connectionString's data source at startup so that it was valid with my computer's name.

This is the part of my app.config that I want to change (replace the
    whole connectionString):

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="MovieDatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MovieDatabase.csdl|res://*/MovieDatabase.ssdl|res://*/MovieDatabase.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=VAIO;initial catalog=MovieDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

This is my code that should do the thing:

```
string HostName = System.Environment.MachineName;
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["MovieDatabaseEntities"].ConnectionString = ("metadata=res://*/MovieDatabase.csdl|res://*/MovieDatabase.ssdl|res://*/MovieDatabase.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=" + HostName + ";initial catalog=MovieDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;");
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

Code runs but doesn't seem to do anything. App.config remains unchanged.
Why?

Comment: Right! Runs, sorry for the mistake

Comment: Have you checked the copied version of app.config (executablename.exe.config) in output directory?

Comment: It is not app.config, it is the executable.exe.config which resides in the bin folder that should be changed. Just to make sure..

Comment: I know, I checked the Project_Name.exe xml config in the bin\Debug folder

Comment: Are you sure the build configuration is Debug and the output directory is `bin/Debug`?

Comment: It is very interesting, but tracing with process monitor shows that the Save operation does not modify the existing exe.config but creates a new file with name \Debug\zsnz2af2.newcfg (random names every time).

Comment: I can run the same code on my machine and the config file changes.

Comment: Just went to SolutionExplorer -> Properties -> Build and checked that the output file is bin\Debug\

Comment: Oh yes, since I was debugging, the actual configuration file is myexe.vshost.exe.Config, and I can see that it is changed too.

Comment: So, if debugging with Visual Studio, you should check the executable.vshost.exe.config..

Comment: What do you expect to be the new value for connection string?

Comment: @Oguz Ozgu  Executable.vshost.exe.config is changed but I wanted to change app.config permanently, how to do this??

Comment: @dotctor I just want to change the data source in Connection String the rest remains intact

Comment: run your application without debugger attached.! press `ctrl + F5`

Comment: As I said. When you start your exe with F5, the name of the running process is executable.vshost.exe, when you start it with CTRL + F5, (or, start it from a command line or so), it is executable.exe. Thus, executable.vshost.exe.config and executable.exe.config are the configuration files, respectively.

Comment: Ok, thx. I was looking in the wrong place for the outcome. I thought that my function will change the original app.config so that I could see the change in the SolutionExplorer -> app.config

Comment: I wonder what happens to questions like these. Resolved by comments, will it stay forever on SO? The unsolved, unanswered number of questions are increasing continuously.

Comment: Well it is more of a personal question than a general, it won't really help anyone else I guess

Comment: You can make an official answer if you want, maybe it will help someone